# How to set icon from theme in PyGTK

Tags: python, button, icons, pygtk

How I can set the icon `emblem-favorite` on button, not from `gtk.StockID`, but from the current theme?

Comment: The stock ID should actually pick the icon from the current theme, I think. Doesn't it?

Comment: But there is no `gtk.STOCK_FAVORITE` or `gtk.STOCK_EMBLEM_FAVORITE` in pygtk. [link](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-stock-items.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work if you do it like this:

```
button.props.image = gtk.image_new_from_icon_name('emblem-favorite', gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
```

Comment: `button = gtk.Button()`

`button.props.image.props.icon_name = 'emblem-favorite'`

It doesn't work: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'props'`

Answer (score 0):

You want to load the themed icon by instantiating a Gio.ThemedIcon(), then convert it to image and add it to your button:

```
icon = Gio.ThemedIcon(name="emblem-favorite")
image = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(icon, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
button.add(image)
```